# Mixing 1dimensional and 2 dimensional elements in an array / hash in Twig

Tags: arrays, cakephp, twig, hash

In my CakePhp app, I can do this:

```
php echo $this->Form->postLink(
  __('Delete'), 
  array('action' => 'delete', $profile['Profile']['id']),
  null, 
  __('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', h($profile['Profile']['id']))
);
```

How can I do this in a Twig template? Twig has array, and hashes, not the sort of combo thing php has. I have tried a few things, none of which are working.  Eg:

```
{{ form.postLink('Delete', {
  0: 'Delete',
  1:{'action' : 'delete'}, 
  2:profile.Profile.id, 
  3: null, 
  4: 'Are you sure you want to delete # %s?'
})|raw }}
```

which outputs

```
<form action="/profiles/delete/Delete/1/Are%20you%20sure%20you%20want%20to%20delete%20%23%20%25s%3F" name="post_517f774917df0" id="post_517f774917df0" style="display:none;" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="data[_Token][key]" value="69a1fb32b5053ddcbd12d081d4dc605af08390f6" id="Token1914918161"><div style="display:none;">
  <input type="hidden" name="data[_Token][fields]" value="12666feca81d6828a076c501deb1385ecb4da673%3A" id="TokenFields1772319507">
  <input type="hidden" name="data[_Token][unlocked]" value="" id="TokenUnlocked1920025967">
 </div>
</form>

<a href="#" onclick="document.post_517f774917df0.submit(); event.returnValue = false; return false;">Delete</a>
```

a working confirm link would look like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete # 8?')) { document.post_517f77f0acddb.submit(); } event.returnValue = false; return false;">Delete</a>
```

Comment: Template lanuages add significant overhead.  If you need to use one, there's a plugin specifically for using Twig in views, https://github.com/predominant/TwigView

Comment: Thanks - I'm using that.  In general its working great - Its just getting twig to pass the right array structure that i'm stuck on

Comment: Have you tried setting escape to false within cake? e.g.  `3:{'escape' : false}`

Comment: just tried adding that, it gives a "rawurlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given" error

Comment: Looks like you're using the security component, maybe try disabling it to see if it's causing problems with TwigView.

Comment: thats a good idea..... but it didn't change the output at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to write about following line

```
{{ form.postLink('Delete', {'action':'delete', profile.Profile.id}, null, __('Are you shure you want delete # %s?', profile.Profile.id) }}
```

but this code is not work.
try following line

```
{{ form.postLink('Delete', {'action':'delete', 0:profile.Profile.id}, null, 'Are you sure you want to delete #' ~ user.User.id ~ '?' | trans) }}
```

ex:

```
array('foo1'=>'bar1', 'aaa', 'foo2'=>'bar2', 'bbb')
```

transform to twig

```
{'foo1':'bar1', 0:'aaa', 'foo2':'bar2', 1:'bbb' }
```